# How to use delegates with Application.OpenForms in a different thread

Tags: vb.net, action, parent, showdialog, anonymous-delegates

Here is the code I got up to and it has no errors but it doesn't seem to work. Can somehow tell me whats wrong with it?

```
        Dim frmCurrentForm As Form
        Dim wasFocused As Boolean = False

        For Each frmCurrentForm In Application.OpenForms
            If Not frmCurrentForm Is Nothing Then
                Dim action As Action(Of Form)
                action = Sub(form)
                             If form.Focused() Then
                                 Dim failedLoginForm As New frmFailedLogin
                                 failedLoginForm.setError("failed blah blah")
                                 'failedLoginForm.Parent = form
                                 failedLoginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
                                 failedLoginForm.ShowDialog()
                                 wasFocused = True
                             End If
                         End Sub

                If (frmCurrentForm.InvokeRequired) Then
                    frmCurrentForm.Invoke(action, New Object() {frmCurrentForm})
                Else
                    action(frmCurrentForm)
                End If

                If wasFocused Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there a specific error message?

Comment: the `.Focused()` is never triggered on any form I focus too. I thought maybe because I am breakpointing and it's not focusing while breakpoints are hit.. but no I took breakpoints off and ran it with full focus on the form and still the `failedLoginForm` never pops out.  Maybe you know of a easier why to do this I want the failedLoginForm to pop out in the center of any form thats currently focused on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using Focused, which I don't think works very well for Forms, try using [Form.ActiveForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx):

```
    Dim frmCurrentForm As Form

    frmCurrentForm = Form.ActiveForm
    If Not frmCurrentForm Is Nothing Then
        Dim action As Action(Of Form)
        action = Sub(form)
                     Dim failedLoginForm As New Form2
                     failedLoginForm.setError("failed blah blah")
                     failedLoginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
                     failedLoginForm.ShowDialog(form)
                 End Sub

        If (frmCurrentForm.InvokeRequired) Then
            frmCurrentForm.Invoke(action, New Object() {frmCurrentForm})
        Else
            action(frmCurrentForm)
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: That's perfect Didn't know of `ActiveForm`. The Delegate stuff isn't needed anymore with ActiveForm, Everything is perfect, but the `failedLoginForm.Parent = frmCurrentForm` makes the Dialog box from appearing do you know whats up there?

Comment: I also tried `failedLoginForm.ShowDialog(Form.ActiveForm)` and it still doesn't pop out. But of course `failedLoginForm.ShowDialog()` works well just doesn't pop out in the Center of the form behind it.

Comment: ShowDialog will work correctly, but don't use Form.ActiveForm as the parent since it may get set to the failedLoginForm depending on timing. Instead, prior to creating a new instance of failedLoginForm, save the ActiveForm in a local variable and then pass that local variable to ShowDialog.

Comment: Running what you suggested still doesn't pop it out.             `failedLoginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
            Dim tmpActiveForm As Form = Form.ActiveForm
            failedLoginForm.ShowDialog(tmpActiveForm)`  Without anything in `ShowDialog()` it appears at the top left of the screen most likely it couldn't find any parent.

Comment: Strange: I wonder if there is something in failedLoginForm that is breaking this. I have tested a couple of different scenarios (changing the WindowStartPosition in the popup form, for example) and it is centered every time. As an alternative, you could always perform the sizing calcs yourself and pass them to the form.

Comment: It works I just tried to remove all the complex delegate stuff and keep it simple such as `Dim failedLoginForm As New frmFailedLogin
            failedLoginForm.setError("blah blah blah")
            failedLoginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
            Dim tmpActiveForm As Form = Form.ActiveForm
            failedLoginForm.ShowDialog(tmpActiveForm)` and cross-threading screws it up.., Now it all works great with the code you previously suggested, sorry for wasting your time. I thought I could keep it simple since no errors appeared and it ran with no exceptions